# Virtual Service Accounts programmatic creation/assigning?

Tags: powershell, service, virtual, accounts

We have a requirement to set our products windows service to use a Virtual Service Account. Going to services.msc and enter in the "NT Service\MyServiceName" **is not an option for us** because we need to do this programatically, from within a script.

So after trying everything under the sun in powershell... i finally broke down and used:

```
net user NT Service\MyServiceName /ADD /Y
```

Which is fine, as a workaround, but due to the space in the 'NT Service" it shows up in the users panel as 'NT' and cuts off there. I've tried;

```
net user 'NT Service\MyServiceName' /ADD /Y
net user "NT Service\MyServiceName" /ADD /Y
```

Neither work.

Ultimately, i'd love to have a Powershell solution. But if someone has an idea on how to do it with net user, without the name being cut off, i'd LOVE to hear from you.

Microsoft's over-distributed but under-exampled link about VSA's:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd548356(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: `net user "NT Service\MyServiceName" /ADD /Y` doesn't work because a username can not have a back-slash in the name. For local accounts you can only specify the part after the back-slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you actually ever need to create those virtual service accounts. When the service is installed, a matching account is automatically created/provisioned. You can use the account without creating it first.

```
icacls .\file.txt /grant "NT Service\MyService:(M)"
```

or

```
sc.exe config MyService obj= "NT SERVICE\MyService"
```

this is for local service accounts, I haven't done much with them in a domain.

Comment: Thank you, maybe this is a misunderstanding on our part. Some folks here wanted to see the NT Service\MyService user in the users control panel. When i add the user user net user, it does actually appear. Weird.

Comment: @BrendanStewart - That's why they called `virtual accounts`, you can use them but they are not `real` in terms of normal user management. A bit confusing, but you don't want all 180+ service accounts show up in your user list. Also if the answer helped you with your issue, you should accept it.